# How to use latest dot net core in Universal Windows Class Library?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, .net-core

I would like to use the latest .NET Core in a new Universal Windows Class Library.

However creating a new library in VS2015 the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` API does not appear to be updated. In particular I want this commit: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/4079/files

My `project.json` looks like:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try upgrading that package using their nightly feed: https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/dotnet-core

Comment: Thanks, my next question then is how? I tried adding that feed to nuget then selected the latest prerelease "Microsoft.NETCore.UniveralWindowsPlatform" and cliked [Update] but get errors like: "NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime.interopservices.pinvoke/index.json"

Comment: try the v2 feed. v3 has been nothing but trouble for me.

Comment: OK I got further using this feed: http://myget.org/F/dotnet-core, which gave me "Package not compatible with UWP" errors, there is now an issue on corefx repo tracking this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/3520